# What is the difference between "Gas" / "Petrol" / "Benzine" / "Gasoline"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, transatlantic-differences

I get always confused with that. What am I suppose to use for what and where (US English / UK English?)

Example:

> I need "*gas / petrol / benzine / gasoline*" for my car.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Gas* is the US term for the fuel put in cars; the Brits call it *petrol*.

Gasoline is the full word that *gas* is shortened from, but no one is likely to say "I need to put some gasoline in my car" (though we would be likely to say "Your garage smells like gasoline!" in the US. When it's being put into a car it's *gas*; when it's being discussed in any other way it's most often *gasoline*).

I've never heard benzine used in reference to car fuel. In fact before looking it up just now, I'd only ever heard it in reference to its use in sodas! I don't think anyone uses *benzine* to describe car fuel.  Suffice it to say that if you use *gas* or *petrol*, depending on your location, you will be perfectly well understood.

Comment: As a Brit I'd say you're correct - I've never seen benzine used as the word for car fuel in English, always petrol (except for diesel cars, which we have a lot more of proportionally than the US does).

Comment: If I recall correctly, my friend always said _gasoline_ even when when talking of putting it in her car, or in sentences like "I need gasoline." Is this something that depends from where a person lives in the USA, or did my friend simply didn't want to use that word to then explain me what the word meant? I know Long Island is particular about some words, but I don't know if that is true about _gasoline_ versus _gas_.

Comment: The German word for gasoline is *das Benzin*. Maybe that's what OP had in mind.

Comment: Photon, the word *Benzine* is used in other languages to mean Diesel.

Comment: Wendi, British people don't use the word *benzine* to mean motor vehicle fuels.

Comment: +1. Car fuel in the US is *gas* (preferable) or *gasoline* and in the UK is *petrol*. *Petroleum*, *benzine* and *benzene* do not refer to fuel, but rather to specific petrochemicals, some of which are used in the manufacture of fuel. *Gas* is not widely understood to mean car fuel in the UK, and *petrol* is not widely understood to mean car fuel in the US. You must use the form that is local to where you are to be properly understood.

Comment: @The Photon You're right about the German word Benzin for Gas/Petrol  (my native language is German). I looked it up before I wrote the question and in Google translate one of the English words for Benzin is Benzine. That's why I added it.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Personally, I find that to be rather odd.  If it *is* distinguished by dialect within the U.S., then it's a distinction I haven't heard of.

Comment: @Tristan, you mean other languages besides English? Or other languages besides German? Leo.org gives *das Benzin* for gas, and *der Diesel* for diesel fuel in German. But I am not a native German speaker and Leo might have it wrong.

Comment: We typically say "gasoline" when we want to make sure that it's clear that we are not talking about natural gas.  "Your garage smells like gasoline" is an example of when we might want to make that distinction.

Comment: Photon, yes, other languages besides English. I didn't know that it is used in German. I have learnt of it being used in languages other than English and German.

Comment: Teo, that's an example of how you can't always get a literal translation between languages.

Comment: In the former Soviet Union, we referred to "petrol"/"gas" as "benzin" as well. That was the Russian word for it, and many of the Republics used it colloquially as well.

Comment: Perhaps not exactly related but in the Turkish language, we use the word `benzin` in place of `gas` in US English. `Gas` would be translated as `gaz` and that would never be used in the context of fueling a car. Just providing some additional info/context.

Answer (score 4):

"I need "Gas / Petrol / Benzine / Gasoline" for my car."

In AmE, "I need gas for my car" refers to gasoline that you would buy at a gas station.

But "I need gas for my stove," or "I need gas for my heater (or furnace)" refers to natural gas that is usually piped into your home by a utility company.

You generally wouldn't say "gasoline" or "natural gas" in informal speech, unless it were needed to clarify which kind of gas you were talking about:

> "They threw gasoline onto the wood stacked up for the bonfire."
>
> "The natural gas plant is a few miles from town."

But:

> "After paying my gas bill, I had just enough money left over to put gas in the car."

If you need petrol for your car, you're someplace where they speak British English.

If you need benzine/benzene for your car, I'm pretty sure you're speaking something other than American or British English.

Comment: In English, the only meaning I'm aware of for "benzene" is a carcinogenic compound which has a ring of six carbon atoms surrounded by hydrogen.  Other languages may have similar-sounding words for gasoline, but I think most motor fuels are primarily blends of heptane, octane, and nonane.

Answer (score 2):

Table of some of the terms used.

| Desription | USA | Britain | Australia |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Light liquid petroleum, C<sub>8</sub>H<sub>18</sub> | gasoline, shortened to gas | Petrol, though gasoline is understood | As Britain |
| Heavier petroleum. A mix averaging at C<sub>12</sub>H<sub>24</sub> ​ | Diesel (mostly for trucks) | Diesel | Diesel |
| Propane (C<sub>3</sub>H<sub>8</sub> ) and butane (C<sub>4</sub>H<sub>10</sub> ) | [Autogas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autogas) or LP Gas | LPG (abbreviation of **L**iquefied **P**etroleum **G**as) | LPG or gas |
| Ethyl alcohol C<sub>2</sub>H<sub>5</sub>OH | Corn ethanol | Ethanol, E100 (rare) | as Britain ? |

Comment: marked CW feel free to extend/correct

Comment: I've never encountered "autogas" in casual usage or signage in the USA.  Always "LP gas" [not LPG] or "propane".  Possibly omitting the word "gas" in some adjectival uses like "LP tank".

Answer (score 1):

*Gas* is short for *gasoline*. You can also put "gas" into your car that is not gasoline, for instance *liquid petroleum gas* which, here in Australia is very popular (and cheap) which is actually gaseous. When people say "fill my car with gas", I instantly think they mean LPG. I think that petrol is a much more satisfactory word, due to the fact that gas can mean something completely different (as an end result). All of it really comes from petroleum anyway, (just refined).

Comment: I've edited the post to salvage the pertinent information; now that it has had the Australian economic commentary stripped, it may be useful, but still lacks a response to benzine and is a possible candidate for deletion.

Answer (score 1):

I can remember as a young child growing up in New Zealand in the fifties, hearing the word benzine being used as a word for petrol. As in, "I'm going to the garage to put some Benzine in my car". Then again, as a child, I could have misinterpreted what was being talked about. There were many different grades of petrol as well as many additives.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain, you call it *petrol*. In India, you call it *petrol*. In the U.S., you call it *gas* or *gasoline*.

Comment: Please refrain from "SMS-speak" (or "text speak") in your answers. **This is a site dedicated to Engish**. It's "you" (not "u"); it's "Britain" (not "britan"); it's "India" (not "india"); It's "In the U.S." (not "in us"). Your answer was just 20 words long, yet I've [found and corrected 8 errors in it](http://ell.stackexchange.com/posts/39612/revisions) (and one person downvoted before I could clean it up). I didn't mind editing this, but in the future, you need to put some care into your answers; quality answers help distinguish the Stack Exchange from other online sites.

Comment: ELL would be the one site where I would hope to find correct English more than all others.